# PHPMailer Not sending Mails To Some Gmail Accounts

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer (Version 5) for user registration. (When user registers to my site the Profile activation code is sent to user to activate it).
PHPMailer works, I tested it many times (I registered Myself with other mails and with gmail too for testing purposes, I always got the activation code), but many users complain that they not getting the activation codes and then I have to send them manually...
I can't understand what is the problem (When I checked my users database there are  many users that got activation codes, but also that couldn't received).. I debug PHPMailer, but there is not any error or problem...

I'm Using PHPMailer With Gmail SMTP:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';              
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port       = 587; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "mymail@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "MyPassword";
$mail->From = "mymail@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = 'www.mysite.com';

$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->WordWrap = 80;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Registration';
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;
$mail->Send();
```

I also tried to use SSL-465, but the result is the same..

Please Help!

Thank you very much in advanced...

Comment: How many users are we talking about? Gmail has a limit of 100-150 per day, SMTP remote access: http://group-mail.com/sending-email/email-send-limits-and-options/

Comment: Thank you JustBaron, Sounds very interesting I'll test it....

Comment: JustBaron I monitor user registration and there is about 20-25 user registration per day...

Comment: But what is the total number of emails sent through your Gmail SMTP per day? If that exceeds 100-150, then it may be possible that some are undelivered.

Comment: You've based your code on a long obsolete example and are not doing any error checking. Start again with [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), make sure you're running [the latest PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/), and do what [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) says.

Comment: Hello Synchro, I did debug as was described in PHPMailer help, I'm using the final version updated it 2 weeks ago (I also thought it was a bug), but after the update the result is the same..

Comment: In my deep belief I think that PHPMailer works perfectly.. Is there any chance that my host has some limitations (but as I'm using gmail smtp can host limit it?).. Really very strange I'm strugling with it for many days, but couldn't find the solution yet...

Comment: worth noting that _sending_ an email does not guarantee _receiving_ an email. A lot happens in between those two things. If you can verify that all your emails are being _sent_ correctly, then the problem is not yours, or at least not directly. Possibly your emails are being marked as spam, for instance. Now, if that's the case, it could be related to how you're sending them or what's in them, or it might not. It's a big topic. You could start by getting your users to add your "from" address and/or domain to their contacts / safe senders list and see if that helps.

Comment: Incidentally, just to say, re: "In my deep belief I think that PHPMailer works perfectly". Belief is great in religions, but almost useless in programming. Verifiable evidence is really the only useful measure of whether your code works. Hoping or believing that something works is just leaving open the possibility that it doesn't, and therefore means that the source of the problem is uncertain. You need to verify each step in the process (line-by-line in the code if it comes to that), plus the bits that aren't done directly by your code, until you find a step that doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Hello ADyson, (I'm using comodo ssl for my site) My domain is also trusted by google, I have verified it with google postmasters, I also chacked other options like spamfilters checked my domin there and everything is ok ... No problems found ...

Comment: Thank you ADyson for correction and suggestion, I'm not native In English, I'll take it in consideration... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using SSL to encrypt the website traffic isn't relevant to whether the emails are delivered or not. Completely different process. If only some of the emails are getting through then either you're hitting a limit on how many you can send, or the email is getting filtered somehow when it reaches the customer-side of the process. Have they even checked their spam folders? Ask someone to test with the contacts / safe-sender option, it's the simplest fix if that's what's happening. It's happened to a site I worked on before now.

Comment: Now I'm working on server side configurations, trying to figure out what's happening and when I'll found a solution will inform everyone...

Greatest Thanks for your help, support and suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **Solved** this problem from server (host). I checked mail functions / configs and found "MAX_EMAIL_PER_HOUR" was set to 30 (Really strange, by default It is 100) So I changed it to 500 and It fixed all PHPMailer Issues...

**In addition:**

Enabling "Allow less secure apps" will usually solve many problem for PHPMailer, and it does not really make your app significantly less secure. (When enabling Google warns you that the App is insecure).

If you Need More security, PHPMailer added support for XOAUTH2 for google, you can use it...

I haven't used this technology before, but I'll play with it as soon as possible ;)

With Best Wishes!